# Divisão por zero no PLSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, divisão

Olá.

O Código abaixo as vezes não executa por causa que é apresentado o erro: Você não pode dividir por zero.
Tentei fazer com um case, mas o meu código é muito grande e o case iria deixar a estrutura lenta e ruim de se tratar em eventuais "manutenções".

Exemplo: Se o divisor for zero, então substitua por 1 para que ele retorne apenas o dividendo.

```
SELECT
(SELECT 8 FROM DUAL) AS ORDEM,
(SELECT 'DESC MEDIO REP %' FROM DUAL) AS DESCRICAO,
ROUND((1-(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(MRG.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2017, MRG.VLRTOT,0))/COALESCE(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(MRG.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2017, MRG.PRTAB,0)),1)))*100,2) AS DESC_2017,
ROUND((1-(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(MRG.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2018, MRG.VLRTOT,0))/COALESCE(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(MRG.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2018, MRG.PRTAB,0)),1)))*100,2) AS DESC_2018,
ROUND((1-(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(MRG.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2019, MRG.VLRTOT,0))/COALESCE(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(MRG.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2019, MRG.PRTAB,0)),1)))*100,2) AS DESC_2019,
ROUND((1-(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(MRG.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2020, MRG.VLRTOT,0))/COALESCE(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(MRG.DTENTSAI, 'YYYY'), 2020, MRG.PRTAB,0)),1)))*100,2) AS DESC_2020,
CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN '#ffd5c6' END BKCOLOR
FROM AD_DADOSMRG_EX MRG
WHERE
MRG.TIPMOV IN ('V', 'D') AND
MRG.GRUPO IN ('VENDAS') AND
MRG.CODVEND = (SELECT PAR.CODVEND FROM TGFPAR PAR WHERE PAR.CODPARCMATRIZ = &CODPARCMATRIZ AND PAR.CODVEND NOT IN 7945 AND ROWNUM = 1)
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Utilize a função [GREATEST](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/greatest.php). Ex: `GREATEST(COALESCE...,1);`

Comment: Funcionou rsrs, obrigado

Comment: Só cuida com uma coisa, se o valor do seu COALESCE for 0.xxxxx, vai pegar 1... Do contrário só pra resolver mesmo com CASE ou DECODE.

Comment: Eu faço assim,  resumido  (CASE XXXX <> 0 THEN YYYY/XXXX ELSE NULL END) , pois divisão por 0 é indeterminado.